# Why is my yum update failing?

Tags: linux, yum, centos-6

Why is my yum no longer working?
It was previously working fine. But seems to have inexplicably stopped working.
FYI, I'm running this on Centos system that is running in VirtualBox on my MacBook Pro.

```
% sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                          |  13 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.net.cen.ct.gov
 * c6-media:
 * epel: mirrors.ucr.ac.cr
 * extras: mirrors.bluehost.com
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: mirrors.bluehost.com
file:///media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file://    /media/CentOS/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
file:///media/cdrecorder/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file://    /media/cdrecorder/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
file:///media/cdrom/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file://    /media/cdrom/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: c6-media. Please verify its     path and try again
```

Comment: Is the CentOS DVD mounted? You could also try running `yum --disablerepo='*media*' update`

Comment: CentOS DVD is unmounted. So that worked. Thanks. Then I tried to install my packages: sudo yum --disablerepo='media' install rpmforge dkms. It can't find rpmforge. How do I point it to the correct repo on the internet that has that package?

Comment: Read [Installing RPMforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CentOS DVD is probably not mounted, so you either mount it so that the *media* repository works, or you stop using that repository. To disable the repository when updating run:

```
yum --disablerepo='*media*' update
```

To disable the repository *permanently* edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/*media*.repo` and set `enabled` to `0`. For example you could use this command:

```
sed --in-place -r 's/^\s*enabled\s*=.*$/enabled=0/' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux (RHEL 6.4) under vmware and you enabled your shared folder option

If Packages is under your share directory.

Create a soft link of your Packages directory under /opt

```
ln -s  /mnt/hgfs/rpm/packages /opt/packages
createrepo  -v /opt/packages
yum clean all
yum update
```

Done.